# Flattening second level of Json array with changing values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using `Snowflake SQL` (new to the syntax and SQL in general) and trying to access the second level of my json array to print the **name** and **value**. How do you go deeper into a json array when the values are constantly changing ie Where it says `Chase Operating - xxxx` there's every different name you can think of, so there's no clear key value to specify.... I've tried using the Flatten function and it just ends up duplicating what I already have.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    pnl.PREPARED: "balanceSheet"."report"."Assets"."Cash and Cash Equivalents"."rows" as "banks"
    //,lateral flatten(input => parse_json(pnl.PREPARED: "balanceSheet"."report"."Assets"."Cash and Cash Equivalents"."rows"))


FROM
      COMPANY c
      LEFT JOIN pnl on  pnl.COMPANY_ID = c.ID

WHERE
(pnl.PREPARED: "balanceSheet"."report"."Assets"."Cash and Cash Equivalents"."rows") is not null
and pnl.FROM_DATE > '2020-01-31'
AND pnl.TO_DATE   <= '2020-2-29'
```

Attempted Flatten function

```
 ,lateral flatten(input => parse_json(pnl.PREPARED: "balanceSheet"."report"."Assets"."Cash and Cash Equivalents"."rows"))
```

Result:

```
-------------
ID: 10001   

Banks: 
{
  "Chase Operating - 1111": {
    "emphasize": false,
    "name": "Chase Operating - 1111",
    "rawValue": 111.6,
    "value": "112"
  },
  "Chase Payroll - 2222": {
    "emphasize": false,
    "name": "Chase Payroll - 2222",
    "rawValue": 222.21,
    "value": "222"
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the sample data

Comment: The full sample data is quite large and due to the obvious nature of it I can't share the raw thing. Would this suffice, so you get a picture of the key levels?

{
"balanceSheet": {
"datePeriod": "Feb 29, 2020",
"report": {
"Assets": {
"Cash and Cash Equivalents": {
"rows": {
"Chase Operating - 1111": {
"emphasize": false,
"name": "Chase Operating - 1111",
"rawValue": 111.6,
"value": "112"
},
"Chase Payroll - 2222": {
"emphasize": false,
"name": "Chase Payroll - 2222",
"rawValue": 222.21,
"value": "222"
}
}}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure , is this what you are looking for

```
create or replace table tablename as
                                      select parse_json(column1) as c
                                   from values
                                     ('{ "balanceSheet": { "datePeriod": "Feb 29, 2020", "report": { "Assets": { "Cash and Cash Equivalents": { "rows": { "Chase Operating - 1111"
                                  : { "emphasize": false, "name": "Chase Operating - 1111", "rawValue": 111.6, "value": "112" }, "Chase Payroll - 2222": { "emphasize": false, "na
                                  me": "Chase Payroll - 2222", "rawValue": 222.21, "value": "222" } }}}}}}') v;



select f.value:name::string as name,
       f.value:value::number as value
from tablename p
    ,lateral flatten( input => p.c , path => 'balanceSheet.report.Assets["Cash and Cash Equivalents"].rows' )f;
```